# Getting Rid of Black Console Window When Running C++ Application

Tags: c++, winapi, netbeans

I am using Netbeans 7.1 to toy around with the AI tutorial I found [here](http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/evolved/nnt1.html).

**edit:** I am using the GCC compiler.

I've gotten everything working, but I can't seem to get the application to compile and run with the Windows Subsystem... The application appears to be written properly for Windows  API, and the executable that came with the source files from that website launches without producing the black console window that my own executable creates.

I've tried adding `-mwindows` as an option to the linker, and I've tried `-Wl,-subsystem,windows`. Neither of these have worked for me. I've provided the main.cpp below.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h> 

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


#include "utils.h"
#include "CController.h"
#include "CTimer.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "CParams.h"


// edited this out, still not working
```

// #pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")

```
///////////////////////GLOBALS ////////////////////////////////////

char*           szApplicationName = "Smart Sweepers v1.0";
char*           szWindowClassName = "sweeper";


//The controller class for this simulation
CController*    g_pController    = NULL; 

//create an instance of the parameter class.
CParams   g_Params;

//---------------------------- Cleanup ----------------------------------
//
//  simply cleans up any memory issues when the application exits
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
void Cleanup()
{
    if (g_pController) 

        delete g_pController;
}
//-----------------------------------WinProc-----------------------------
//
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, 
                                        UINT msg, 
                            WPARAM wparam, 
                            LPARAM lparam)
{
    //these hold the dimensions of the client window area
    static int cxClient, cyClient;

    //used to create the back buffer
    static HDC        hdcBackBuffer;
    static HBITMAP  hBitmap;
    static HBITMAP  hOldBitmap; 


    switch(msg)
    {   
        case WM_CREATE: 
        {
            //seed the random number generator
            srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

            //get the size of the client window
            RECT rect;
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);

            cxClient = rect.right;
            cyClient = rect.bottom;

            //setup the controller
            g_pController = new CController(hwnd);

                //create a surface for us to render to(backbuffer)
            hdcBackBuffer = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);

            HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

            hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc,
                                                            cxClient,
                                                            cyClient);
            ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

            hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcBackBuffer, hBitmap); 
        } 

        break;

        //check key press messages
        case WM_KEYUP:
        {
            switch(wparam)
            {

                case VK_ESCAPE:
                {
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                }

                break;

                case 'F':
                    {
                        g_pController->FastRenderToggle();
                    }

                    break;

        //reset the demo
        case 'R':
          {
             if (g_pController)
             {
               delete g_pController;
             }

             //setup the new controller
                   g_pController = new CController(hwnd);
          }

          break;

            }//end WM_KEYUP switch
        }

        break;

        //has the user resized the client area?
        case WM_SIZE:
        {
            cxClient = LOWORD(lparam);
            cyClient = HIWORD(lparam);

            //resize the backbuffer accordingly
            SelectObject(hdcBackBuffer, hOldBitmap);

            HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

            hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc,
                                                             cxClient,
                                                             cyClient);
            ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

            hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcBackBuffer, hBitmap); 
        } 

        break;

        case WM_PAINT: 
        {
      PAINTSTRUCT ps;

          BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            //fill our backbuffer with white
            BitBlt(hdcBackBuffer,
             0,
             0,
             cxClient,
             cyClient,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             WHITENESS);

            //render the mines and sweepers
            g_pController->Render(hdcBackBuffer);

            //now blit backbuffer to front
            BitBlt(ps.hdc, 0, 0, cxClient, cyClient, hdcBackBuffer, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); 

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        } 

        break;

        case WM_DESTROY: 
        {
            SelectObject(hdcBackBuffer, hOldBitmap);

            //clean up our backbuffer objects
            DeleteDC(hdcBackBuffer);
            DeleteObject(hBitmap); 

      // kill the application, this sends a WM_QUIT message 
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        } 

        break;

        default:break;

    }//end switch

    // default msg handler 
    return (DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam));

}//end WinProc


//-----------------------------------WinMain-----------------------------------------
//  Entry point for our windows application
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hinstance,
                              HINSTANCE hprevinstance,
                              LPSTR lpcmdline,
                              int ncmdshow)
{

    WNDCLASSEX winclass; 
    HWND       hwnd;     
    MSG        msg;      

    // first fill in the window class stucture
    winclass.cbSize       = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    winclass.style            = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    winclass.lpfnWndProc    = WindowProc;
    winclass.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    winclass.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    winclass.hInstance      = hinstance;
    winclass.hIcon            = LoadIcon(hinstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
    winclass.hCursor          = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW); 
    winclass.hbrBackground= NULL; 
    winclass.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
    winclass.lpszClassName= szWindowClassName;
    winclass.hIconSm      = LoadIcon(hinstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));


    // register the window class
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&winclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Error Registering Class!", "Error", 0);
    return 0;
    }

    // create the window (one that cannot be resized)
    if (!(hwnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,                                   
                                              szWindowClassName,                        
                                              szApplicationName,                        
                                              WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU,
                              GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)/2 - CParams::WindowWidth/2,
                              GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)/2 - CParams::WindowHeight/2,                                    
                                              CParams::WindowWidth,
                              CParams::WindowHeight,                
                                              NULL,                                 
                                              NULL,                             
                                              hinstance,                                
                                              NULL)))   
    {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Error Creating Window!", "Error", 0);
        return 0;
    }

    //Show the window
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT );
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    //create a timer
    CTimer timer(CParams::iFramesPerSecond);

    //start the timer
    timer.Start();

    // Enter the message loop
    bool bDone = FALSE;

    while(!bDone)
    {

        while( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) ) 
        {
            if( msg.message == WM_QUIT ) 
            {
                //Stop loop if it's a quit message
                bDone = TRUE;
            } 

            else 
            {
                TranslateMessage( &msg );
                DispatchMessage( &msg );
            }
        }

        if (timer.ReadyForNextFrame() || g_pController->FastRender())
        {   
          if(!g_pController->Update())
            {
                //we have a problem, end app
                bDone = TRUE;
            }

            //this will call WM_PAINT which will render our scene
            InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
            UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    }                   

    }//end while


    // Clean up everything and exit the app
    Cleanup();
    UnregisterClass( szWindowClassName, winclass.hInstance );

    return 0;

} // end WinMain
```

Comment: What errors do you get / why can't you get it to compile?

Comment: Seems like the problem isn't errors -- it's that the app ends up being compiled for the console subsystem, and therefore gets a console window even though it doesn't need one.  Apparently it's just that the linker options are wrong.  In order to fix this, it'd be important to know what compiler is being used behind the scenes.  I'm guessing GCC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a bit strange, but windows subsystem application uses WinMainCRTStartup as entry point. So the following line looks inconsistent:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")
```

It probably should be `"/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:WinMainCRTStartup"` or `"/SUBSYSTEM:console /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup"`

On the other hand, I never trried to make a windows app with gcc. It may completely ignore this `#pragma`... Anyway, try to comment it out and see what happens. Generally compiler should be able to select the proper entry point without the compile time parameter anyway.

Comment: I put that in there to try and fix the problem, it didn't work. I forgot that I included it in the source code in my OP, however, the application is still launched with a console regardless of whether the comment is there or not, or whether I use the string you provided.

Comment: should I just try switching to minGW or something?

Comment: I would, just out of principle.  Cygwin sucks for native Windows apps.    It's designed for programs that need to make believe they're running in *nix.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't aware. Hopefully that solves it, I will come back and post after I swap them out

Comment: Okay, while not technically a direct answer to my problem, switching to minGW has fixed this for me, and my application now launches pretty-like. Thank you to everyone. Chao, if you made an answer instead of a comment you would get the "accepted answer"